# Call javascript function from remote flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a flash file that is located on one server, http://www.somewhere.com/myflash.swf

A web application on second server, http://www.righthere.com, contains html page that embedding that flash file.

The flash file at some point calls a javascript function, which is not triggered.

If I copy the swf file locally where web app is, the javascript function is triggered, so flash it self fine.

How do I make it work when flash located on remote server?

Thanks in advanced!

Names of places have been changed for the sake of the plot =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. This is the reference:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c9b.html